# Is my lookup table with 50,000 entries too big for MCU memory (dsPIC33EP256MC506)?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

I want to implement a 2-input 1-output fuzzy logic controller using lookup table on the [dsPIC33EP256MC506 microcontroller](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70000657H.pdf). I am comparing the lookup table and actual fuzzy logic controller side by side in Simulink. In order to minimize the error between the lookup table and actual controller, I am having to generate a huge table, having around 50,000 entries. The input 1 range is `-5000 to 5000`, input 2 range is `-1000 to 1000` and output range is `-9999 to 9999`. I am using Simulink code generation.

I went over the datasheet's memory section, but still need some expert guidance in relating the lookup table size to the program memory size. 
My questions are: how can I find out if this lookup table will fit into the program memory? How can I estimate the approximate size of the lookup table? What are key things to look for in datasheet or the lookup table from practical implementation viewpoint?

Comment: Although lookup table would do it, implementing fuzzy controller in code would be much better and much more flash/ram friendly. Believe me, it's not that hard, and it would allow to change parameters without need to reflash whole lookup table each time you make changes.

Comment: I'm actually Simulink C-code generation feature, so not coding at all. However, the lookup table is generated through a combination of MATLAB code/fuzzy toolbox commands.

Comment: You might wish to investigate the use of higher-order interpolation, and/or wavelet interpolation to lower the size of the table.

Answer (score 4):

You say your lookup table will contain `50000` elements and each element will have the range of `-9999 to 9999`. That means each element will need 16 bits (= 2 bytes) of memory. So the whole LUT will need `50000 x 2 bytes = 100000 bytes = aprox. 97.6 Kbytes`.

Your microcontroller has  256 Kbytes of Flash memory and 32 Kbytes of RAM. So your program/Flash memory would be enough for the LUT. To place the table in program memory you need to declare it as const: `const int16_t LUT[] = { ... };`

Comment: With perfect coding, a table element occupies 14.288 bits (there's 9999*2+1 values). That's 89298 bytes of storage needed. More practically, you can store 103 values in 184 bytes, losing only 5% of one bit. That's 89321 bytes with a 184 byte codeword.